# jinja2 : how to match string to json field

Tags: python, json, templates, jinja2

I'm having a problem in a jinja template. If I have an object 'jsonobj' like so:

```
{
    "type": "test",
    "people": [{"name": "bill", "age": 43}]
}
```

in my template I'm trying to do an if like

```
  {% if 'test' is jsonobj.type %}
  <!-- some html here -->
  {% else %}
  <!-- some other html here -->
  {% endif %}
```

but I get an error:
`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endfor'. You probably made a nesting mistake. Jinja is expecting this tag, but currently looking for 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.`

when I add curlies around `jsonobj.type` I get

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '{'
```

Was looking at the docs [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-tests.string) and I thought it should work...any ideas?
thanks

I tried any variation I could think of; ==, is, isin and so on. Tried wrapping json obj in one and two sets of curlies. Did lots of googling

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget `endif` tag at end?

```
    {% if 'test' is jsonobj.type %}
    ...
    {% else %}
    ...
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: no, the endif is there, I just forgot to include in the example. I updated the example post, sorry for that oversight

Answer (score 0):

{% endif %} it seems you forgot to turn off the if blog

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by making sure the whitespace/indenting was even. That seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).